# Did Malachi soften the policy of Ezra on the question of Divorce? (Ezra 10, Malachi 2)

Tags: marriage, malachi, ezra

In the Book of Ezra, Jews who intermarried with foreign wives responded to Ezra's message by determining to divorce their wives and also to send away any children produced by the marriage:

Ezra 10

> We have indeed betrayed our God by taking as wives foreign women of
> the peoples of the land. Yet in spite of this there still remains a
> hope for Israel. 3 Let us therefore enter into a covenant before our
> God to dismiss all our foreign wives and the children born of them, in
> keeping with what you, my lord, advise, and those who are in dread of
> the commandments of our God. Let it be done according to the law! 4
> Rise, then, for this is your duty!

But in Malachi 2:14-16 we read:

> the Lord is witness
> between you and the wife of your youth with whom you have broken faith,
> though she is your companion, your covenanted wife. Did he not make them one, with flesh and spirit?
> And what does the One require? Godly offspring! You should be on guard, then, for your life,
> and do not break faith with the wife of your youth. 16 For I hate divorce,
> says the Lord, the God of Israel.

One way of reading Malachi is to understand that he is urging the Jews not to take Ezra's teaching too far: as long as the foreign wife has converted to Judaism, God wants the couple to stay together and raise 'godly offspring.' Another way is to interpret Malachi as teaching that there is no such thing as a "covenanted wife" unless the woman is Jewish. Are there other scriptures that can help us understand Malachi and Ezra's teaching here? How absolute was the Ezra's policy? Were there no exceptions if the woman was willing to raise their children as Jews?

Answer (score 0):

In Malachi 2:11 it says:

Judah has been unfaithful. A detestable thing has been committed in Israel and in Jerusalem: Judah has desecrated the sanctuary the Lord loves by marrying women who worship a foreign god.

So both Malachi and Ezra agree that intermarrying with foreign women with foreign gods displeases the Lord.

Knowing this, we can understand that when Malachi speaks against divorce, he is talking about men divorcing *Israelite* women.

**Conclusion:**
Malachi is talking about why it’s wrong to divorce Israelite women since he already has said that marrying foreign women is wrong.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It's clear that Malachi denounced marrying foreign women, but why does this mean he approved of divorcing them? Against this idea we have God supporting Moses' marriage to the Midianite Zipporah, the Canaanite Rahab's inclusion in the lineage of Jesus, Boaz' marriage to the Moabite Ruth (which produced King David), and - in the NT - Timothy's birth to a Jewish mother and a Gentile father. The parable of the Good Samaritan likewise shows that a mixed race believer is often a better Israelite than even a pure-bred priest or Levite.

Comment: First of all, we can guess that Malachi approved of divorcing them because if he thought it was detestable to marry them, than he would think that the men who married foreign women should separate themselves from the foreign women. Also, Malachi 2:11 says, “ Judah has desecrated the sanctuary the Lord loves by marrying women who worship a foreign god.” Zipporah became part of the Israelite covenant when she circumcised her son, Rahab accepted the Lord, and Ruth said “your God my God”. All these women worship the Lord so this is not even an argument.